# Renaming css stylesheet file causes bad MIME type - Apache

Tags: css, apache

I've come over a curious problem. When I include my stylesheet as following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

When I rename the file to explicitly 'setup.css' it causes a bad content type

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

However, changing on any other name is just fine.

I'm running Apache 2.4.26 and PHP 7.0.21 whether it matters or not.

Comment: Is this on shared hosting? The server might have a catch for files named `setup` and attempting to fist display another web page. This could be set in the Apache conf file or if you see a `.htaccess` file.

Comment: No, I'm running that locally.

I don't think it's caused by .htaccess although it might be.
The only mention of 'setup' is
`RewriteRule setup setup.php [L]`

Comment: Then might be the `RewriteRule setup setup.php [L]` You can comment it out and verify.

Comment: I see, it didn't came up on my mind, it's a regular expression, ah.. sorry for bothering and thanks :)